# What do these notation mean in this research paper?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm currently reading a research paper on finding a correlation between daily stock price volatilities, and the individual stock prices.

I'm trying to understand the theory behind the author's realized return volatility measurement method, but with my limited 1st year stats knowledge, I'm having trouble understanding what the notations in the equations (1),(2), and (3) mean. I get that they're trying to create a better model of predicting future stock prices by looking at the correlation between volatility and stock prices, but what exactly is their theory?

Link to the paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=809073BDEAA66F241A45C0F293FE6D1E?doi=10.1.1.414.9909&rep=rep1&type=pdf

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have never heard of stochastic processes and stochastic differential equations, this paper is presumably beyond your reach.

Comment: You’re probably right, but would you mind giving it a try regardless? I am very interested in the subject.

Comment: What @Xi'an is trying to say is that even to understand equation $(1)$ requires extensive preparation and study beyond anything in a first year statistics education.  It usually takes the first half of a thick book on stochastic processes to introduce all the theory needed to explain what that equation means--which is why your quotation refers explicitly to two of them.  We don't doubt your ability to master that material--we only question the assumption that even a small part of this knowledge could be imparted in a Q&A thread.